# What is login class in bsd?

Tags: freebsd, bsd

Can anyone explain to me what is `login class` in simple words.

Comment: The handbook has [this section](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/security-resourcelimits.html#resource-limits) dedicated to the subject.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Login classes has been a part of FreeBSD for as long I can remember. It allows the system administrator (root) to set resource constraints for users, or a group of users as configured in */etc/login.conf*.

This is particularly useful on multi-user servers such as webhosting and shell providers.

**These kind of constraints involves:**

- CPU utilization
- Memory utilization
- Maximum open files (file descriptors)
- Biggest individual file allowed to create within that login class (not redundant to quotas).
- And a lot more.

In case you make any tweaks, or add new login classes you have to use *cap_mkdb* to generate a capability database from /etc/login.conf.

**Apply changes:** `cap_mkdb /etc/login.conf`

Answer (score 2):

Think cgroups.  Also, you might find "ps auxw -o class" useful, to see what processes belong to which class, and "su -c classname", to change your login class for testing purposes.